Sharing Session Between Two C# Microservices Using Redis
I am trying to share a session between two C# microservices using Redis. Currently, RedisDB is only adding keys with the format AuthMicroservice:* and an DataProtectionKeys (list) entry. When the second microservice attempts to retrieve the session using HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId"), it returns null (it works in authmicroservices).
Here’s what I have so far:
Session Configuration in AuthMicroservice  (is storing cookie session): :
var redisConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");
var redis = redisConnectionString != null ? ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString) : null;
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtectionKeys");

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = redisConnectionString;
    option.InstanceName = "AuthMicroservice:";
});
// Configure Session
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
    options.Cookie.Name = "Session";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

and GameMicroservice session:
var redisConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");
var redis = redisConnectionString != null ? ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString) : null;
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtectionKeys");

builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = redisConnectionString;
    option.InstanceName = "GameMicroservice:";
});

// Configure Session
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);
    options.Cookie.Name = "Session";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

What could be causing this issue, both connected to same redis db, and how can I properly share the session between the two microservices?

Firstly, option.InstanceName = "AuthMicroservice:"; must be the same. 
Another problem is you will need to disable the AutomaticKeyGeneration, or it will use new key every time.
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtectionKeys")
    .DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();

Just note that you could enable keygenerate to initiate.
